# Can't get POST to work in jQuery AJAX/Web API - parameter always null

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I can't seem to make binding work for complex types. I've tried most of the suggestions here on SO but can't seem to make it work. Parameter is always null.

```
function createFile(filename, x, y, width, height) {
    var image = {
        Filename: filename,
        X: x,
        Y: y,
        Width: width,
        Height: height
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Server.Domain() + "media/createFile",
        data: JSON.stringify(image),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            //
        }
    });
}
```

And the Web API method:

```
    [Route("api/media/createFile")]
    [HttpPost]
    public bool CreateFile(ItemDto item)
    {
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            //
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return success;
    }
```

and the type:

```
public class ItemDto
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

The Web API gets called but the 'item' parameter is always null. I tried adding FromBody, removing content-type (some says it should not be present but I think that shouldn't be the case since i'm passing JSON) but still to no avail.

**EDIT:**

This is what is sent
"{"Filename":"30.jpg","X":29.999999999999993,"Y":29.999999999999993,"Width":240.00000000000003,"Height":240.00000000000003}"

**UPDATE:**

Changing the JavaScript object to this binds successfully:

```
var image = {
        Filename: "a",
        X: "1",
        Y: "2",
        Width: "3",
        Height: "4"
    };
```

the sent value is

```
"{"Filename":"a","X":"1","Y":"2","Width":"3","Height":"4"}"
```

Is there a problem on my original values?

**UPDATE 2:**

I changed X to 1.1111111111 and tested with and without double-quotes. The parameter is not null but X is equal to zero in Web API.

Comment: Did you look in the console to see what was sent?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to include. See edit

Comment: Seems you need to do `X:Math.round(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the data type was wrong:

```
public class ItemDto
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

I was sending numbers with decimal points. Changing the data type to decimal fixed the problem.

Comment: Better choice is to send ints instead of floats